# Is there a way to add SSH Custom by countries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

So far I have this:

[image]

What I want is, `SSH` - `TCP` - `22` - `Custom` - `Phil.ippines.Addre.ss`/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Security Groups require either a **CIDR range** or the **ID of another Security Group**.

If you wish to restrict access to your application (web traffic) to a particular country, you could use **Amazon CloudFront** and [Restrict the Geographic Distribution of Your Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html).

However, this will not work for SSH (which is shown in your picture). It is advisable that you **restrict SSH/RDP access to the absolute minimum**, such as one IP address. It would not be a good idea to open SSH to an entire country.

Comment: I'm going to do some research on this. Thanks for the leads.